# Add a CSS border on hover without moving the element

Tags: css

I have a row that I am applying a background highlight to on hover.

```
.jobs .item:hover {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

However, as the border adds 1px **additional** to the element, it makes it 'move'. How would I compensate for the above movement here (without using a background image)?

Comment: Does your element have a defined height? If so, you can 1) use `box-sizing: border-box` (with the necessary prefixes) for modern browsers, or 2) cheat by adding a border the same color as the default background and shave 1 pixel off the specified height.

Comment: see my answer below and let me know if a am lagging here, so i can understand you problem more specifically.

Comment: My situation does not work with the solutions below, which I tried before even seeing this thread. I have multiple different buttons that 1. already have borders and 2. have different margins on them. I cannot simply make a transparent border because I already need a small border when not hovering. I cannot just decrease the margin by the differential because each margin is different, and I can't do this with calc(). I have to either go to each individual element with different css and set the hover margin differently (awful) or make the border a **gradient from my color to transparent**

Answer (score 640, accepted):

You can make the border transparent. In this way it exists, but is invisible, so it doesn't push anything around:

```css
.jobs .item {
   background: #eee;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.jobs .item:hover {
   background: #e1e1e1;
   border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class="jobs">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

For elements that already have a border, and you don't want them to move, you can use negative margins:

```css
.jobs .item {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.jobs .item:hover {
   background: #e1e1e1;
    border: 3px solid #d0d0d0;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jobs">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Another possible trick for adding width to an existing border is to add a `box-shadow` with the spread attribute of the desired pixel width.

```css
.jobs .item {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.jobs .item:hover {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class="jobs">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyone seen a way to solve this by using CSS attribute `box-sizing:border-box;`?

Comment: @tim yes, it works with `box-sizing:border-box;` too.

Comment: It's better if you use color transparent:

Comment: @Duopixel It does not seem to work with `box-sizing: border-box` fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2ngmktw/. Can you add more info?

Comment: @SungWonCho for `box-sizing: border-box` to work you would need to specify the width and the height of element, which I assume is not what you want. Use the technique described in the answer https://jsfiddle.net/g9qc2kg3/

Comment: I came across this by accident and was surprised that no one had included background-clip: padding-box; with the border: 1px solid transparent; css. Seems a must for me to include both entries when addressing this issue esp. with box-sizing:border-box;.

Comment: This doesn't work. The box still expands when the border is applied .Yes, I am specifying width and height.

Comment: @felwithe making this box-sizing: content-box; made the accepted solution work brilliantly.

Comment: What if I already have a border in default state? This answer doesn't work then.

Comment: @omeralper added two alternatives for you

Answer (score 131):

add `margin:-1px;` which reduces `1px` to each side. or if you need only for side you can do `margin-left:-1px` etc.

Comment: That was the best solution for me because, in my case, I set a 1px border to the orignal element and want to get, on hover, a thicker border (3px). Using `margin: -2px;` indeed works.

Comment: Indeed the best solution when the border thickness changes from one state to another.

Comment: To clarify and formalize this solution: add the negative margin only when applying the thicker border, and use a margin size equal to the thick border minus the thin border. So to transition from a 2px border to a 5px border on hover, you'd use `.some-class{ box-sizing: content-box; border: 2px solid #333 }` then you'd have `.some-class:hover{ margin: -3px; border: 5px solid #333}` (Or whatever colors you like). `box-sizing: content-box` is also needed on the element in question to keep it from shifting when the thick border is applied. [codepen](https://codepen.io/aleph_one/pen/OJVEoGQ)

Answer (score 23):

Try this it might solve your problem.

Css:

```
.item{padding-top:1px;}

.jobs .item:hover {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-top:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jobs">
    <div class="item">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle for output: http://jsfiddle.net/dLDNA/

Comment: here is the new one: http://jsfiddle.net/fbfjw/3/embedded/result/

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/q8n11ng6v/test_2.png

Comment: Only this one worked for me. The `margin` and the `border: transparent` ones alter the content inside.

Answer (score 21):

Add a `border` to the regular item, the same `color` as the `background`, so that it cannot be seen. That way the item has a `border: 1px` whether it is being hovered or not.