# I want to add a border to my button on hover event without moving the button or anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

right now I want to implement a border on hover on a button.

That button is in a div together with 3 other buttons. However, as soon as I hover over it, the border is being displayed, but at the same time the button expands the size of the added border as well, which is not what I have in my mind.

I made a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: [Click me](https://jsfiddle.net/L9dfg74f/3/)

I read up about this topic here, and I indeed found a solution, by adding `margin-top: 3px;`
to the hover classes, however, that "squeezes" the button, which is not what I want.

Instead, I want the button to not look compressed or anything, but rather simply with a 4px border overlaying the top 4 px of the button.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well received question!

Comment: You may also find this question of interest: [Add a CSS border on hover without moving the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612758/add-a-css-border-on-hover-without-moving-the-element)

Comment: Set all your buttons to Box-sizing: Border-box in your CSS. Then the problem goes away.

Comment: Are you looking for the one in the red section here: http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcoady/L9dfg74f/7/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using a box shadow instead, as this doesn't actually affect the positioning:

```css
a {
  transition: all 0.8s;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align: center;
  color:black;
}
a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 -3px red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">HOVER ME</a><a href="#">NOTICE</a><a href="#">HOW</a><a href="#">I</a><a href="#">DON'T</a><a href="#">MOVE?</a>
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could just add "transition: all 0.8s;", very cool +1.

Comment: That works with any animatable property.

Comment: does this also work on old versions of IE. ie IE7 and older?

Comment: @Ankit: I haven't really supported ie8 for a while now. But has better support than box-sizing (which only has partial support) according to http://caniuse.com/

Comment: less than 0.1% of people are on IE7

Comment: @DanBeaulieu yes, i know and I hate those 0.1% people. But you also have to keep them in consideration. Specially when you are making a web application for a company's internal use.

Comment: thats what Im doing right now actually... and i've just found out that about 50% of the staff here are on IE 8 so I certainly understand what you mean. A dream of mine is to rally up the developer community to purposely make anything on IE8 and under look terrible and unusable.

Comment: @Ankit: If they are on IE7, then the box shadow won't show. It won't break any of the functionality. You could even give them instructions as to how to update (Even Microsoft is [stopping support for IE8 soon enough](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/12659/20140811/dingdong-internet-explorer-8-is-dead-microsoft-will-end-its-life-in-january-2016.htm))

Comment: Very elegant solution. +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

I created a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/alexcoady/ogoy21dq/
And one with just top or bottom http://jsfiddle.net/alexcoady/ogoy21dq/2/

Use margin to replace border-width when it's not visible.

```
button {
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

button:hover {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @afasm93 this is a good solution, one could also set the initial border to white (or whatever the background is) and then just simply change the color of the border on hover

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: Or one could set it to transparent....

Comment: @jbutler483 there you go

Comment: one isn't able to do either as there is a 1px default border in OP's style

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- use the `box-shadow` ***[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pjn4hfwd/)***

```
.functionButton:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 #a3def1;
}
```

Comment: always the the correct answer !!

Comment: By default OP has a 1px border though

Answer (score 2):

Style your button to have `vertical-align` to `top`. Add the following style to the bottom of your CSS:

```
#functionButtonDiv button{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9dfg74f/6/)

---

*Read up:* [`vertical-align` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 2):

Try to understand what is happening.

You want buttons not be squeezed, but a border on top to be added.

**Initially** your button `height` was `25px` and `border` was `1px`.

**On hover** your `height` remains same however the `border` increases by `3px`, hence making your button to squeeze.

**Solution**:

**Hover**: `height` has to be increased to accomodate increased `border`( `4px-1px = 3px`)  (*in order not to squeeze the button)*.

If you do this only you will observe that the button starts shifting down.

To avoid it add `margin of 4-1 = 3px` to your `functionButton class` to compensate the increased `height`.

Similarly add a `margin` of -`3px` in `hover class` as the `height` is already increased by `3px`.

```
.functionButton{
  width:60px;
  height:25px;
  border: 1px solid #A3DEF1;
  border-left: none;
  outline:none;
  background: #F2F5FD;
    margin-top:3px;    //added to avoid shifting of buttons down on hover (Here it compensates the increased height while hovering)
}

.functionButton:hover{
  border-top: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
  height:28px;   //increased height to accomodate the increased border
  margin-top:-3px;      //negative margin to avoid shifting of button down
}
```

```css
.functionButton{
  width:60px;
  height:25px;
  border: 1px solid #A3DEF1;
  border-left: none;
  outline:none;
  background: #F2F5FD;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.functionButton:hover{
  width:60px;
  height:28px;
  border-top: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
  margin-top:-3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="functionButtonDiv" id="functionButtonDiv">
    <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy2</button>
    <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy3</button>
    <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Or change to `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: user has many solutions... my focus was to explain him, what is happening..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I found the box shadow answer to be the best fitting one, but the explanation made the problem clear for me !

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need Javascript for this.

You can use box-sizing to make sure that borders are included in your dimensions and vertical alignment to maintain position.

```
button {
    vertical-align: top;    
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
button {
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.functionButtonChat {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #A3DEF1;
  outline: none;
  background: #F2F5FD;
}
.functionButtonChat:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
  border-top: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
}
.functionButton {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #A3DEF1;
  border-left: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #F2F5FD;
}
.functionButton:hover {
  border-top: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
}
```

```html
<div class="functionButtonDiv" id="functionButtonDiv">
  <button type="button" class="functionButtonChat">Dummy1</button>
  <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy2</button>
  <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy3</button>
  <button type="button" class="functionButton">Dummy4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you might want to have a quick check on this ;P

Answer (score 0):

use following css i have made some changes in ur css and its working as per ur requirement try the following

```
.functionButtonChat{
     width:80px;
     height:25px;
     outline:none;
     background: #F2F5FD;
}

.functionButtonChat:hover{
     border: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
}

.functionButton{
     width:80px;
     height:25px;
     outline:none;
     background: #F2F5FD;
}

.functionButton:hover{
      border: 4px solid #A3DEF1;
}
```