# Remove unwanted hover effect

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have an hover effect written in CSS:

```
h2:hover{
     background-color: #FFE4B5;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
     border-top: 1px solid #888;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

But i noticed that when i hover each of the menu options, the text would move slightly up and then down. I didn't add anything that would cause this? I don't think.. How can i fix this and make them stay in place when hovering?

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/filecount/d1y5eu5x/4/)

Comment: As well as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612758/add-a-css-border-on-hover-without-moving-the-element and a bunch of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the border that's being added and removed that's causing this issue.

Two options: add `box-sizing: border-box` to the item or add transparent borders to the non-hovered elements.

**Example box-sizing:**

```
h2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Example border:**

```
h2 {
  border-top: transparent 1px solid;
  border-bottom: transparent 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: border-sizing didn't seem to work, but the transparent border worked. Thanks!

Comment: @JennyC – If this helped solve your question, be sure to mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The movement comes from the border being added and removed on hover. An easy fix is to give the h2 element a transparent border of the same width when it's not being hovered:

```
h2{
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
     border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```