# Margin top won't work when trying to prevent element from moving upon adding border

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**OBJECTIVE**

I want my button to go from a black background to a white background with a black border on hover.

**INITIAL PROBLEM**

Upon adding the border to the "a" element, the text within it moves. I found a few solutions, including from SO itself, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612758/add-a-css-border-on-hover-without-moving-the-element) and so I added an invisible border to the non-hover state.

**NEW PROBLEM**

I can't seem to find a way to move the text to compensate for the border.

**INFORMATION**

My site is still on localhost so, unfortunately, I can't share a link. However, this is the demo of the theme I'm using:

https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/product-category/women/

The button is the "Add to cart" one.

Please forgive me, I'm a noob and don't know if it would be helpful to share any specific code or anything other than the link above but, if so, please let me know and I'll edit the post to include it.

**EDIT**

Margin-top works on this page but also raises the text:
https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/product/knitted-top/

It doesn't work elsewhere such as on the main page's products:
https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/

(the green "Add to cart" button)

Comment: What do you mean by; I can't seem to find a way to move the text to compensate for the border ?? because when adding a transparent border everything should stay the same

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for replying. I added a black border intending the text to actually move so that I could then compensate by using "margin-top". This way the text would be pre-moved in the non-hover state and wouldn't jump arond.

Comment: and now `margin-top` isn't working?

Comment: Exactly, no idea why. I'm a noob

Comment: Could you try `box-sizing: border-box` on your element instead of trying an invisible border when not hovered? This attribute will include padding and borders in the overall dimensions of the button

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! Unfortunately the text still moved once the border was applied on hover, even using when "!important"

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Copied the button and the rules for `.button` from the site you pointed to. Then just added the two rules for `.button:hover`.

Update per @Python Millionaire's comment. Added rules `display: flex;   align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to `.button`. To make the aligning more visible, increased the height of the button.

```css
.button {
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(59, 181, 74);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 3.304px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 276.133px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply! Unfortunately the same problem persists. I am able to add the border, which is what your code did also. What I am unable to do is centralize the button's text. Notice how "Add to car" is lower than it should be: https://i.ibb.co/b1FWQ2t/image.png

Comment: You're welcome! Please check the updated answer for vertical alignment of the button text.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. It's a step in the right direction! It works for the button (which is an actual "<button>") on the product page https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/product/knitted-top/, though it moves the button to the center on hover. Unfortunately it doesn't work for the buttons (which are really "<a>") on the other pages such as the "Add to cart" button here: https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/product-category/women/

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I'm confused about what you want. Anyway, hope you can figure it out.